# firebase performance and scalability

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to know how long it may take for a query with thousands of records, possibly in the future up to millions of records.

I will have a collection of schedules that will store schedules from various healthcare professionals, I really don't know yet if I should store schedules within the professional or within the unit.

There are indexes that can be created in Firebase, but how can I get schedules in a way that is not complex?

**1. First way.**

```
db.collection('unity').doc('6BfbptQ8blacBLi1GNIJ').collection('schedules').
```

**2. Second way.**

```
 db.collection('unity').doc('6BfbptQ8blacBLi1GNIJ')
.collection('professionals').
doc('Z6JDd0Ek7WO8yqiZJkBuJooF1FH3')
.collection('schedules').
```

With the second way I will have to go through all the professionals of the unit and get all the schedules of each professional and add the count to get the total schedules that the unit has, that would not be cool.

I wonder if I can perform well when the collection has thousands or millions of records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the volume of data.  Thousands of documents is not a problem, but you have to keep in mind that you have to pay the cost of transferring all of that data across the network, possibly over a mobile connection.  That could be a lot of data, and could take a lot of time.  The client device making the request will also need available memory to store all those results.

Without knowing *exactly* the query results you're trying to transfer, the quality of the network, and the memory available to the app, it's not possible to say if this is going to work.  You should benchmark this for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm in the structuring phase and I'm defining it yet. If I make a query with a query that searches the records within a month for example, if this collection where I search has many records can it still take? With indexing by the date of the schedule, is it possible to get the one month schedules with performance even having thousands of records in the collection?

Comment: The size of the collection doesn't matter at all.  It could have billions of records and not have a problem.  It's the size of the result set (the matching documents) that matters for performance.

Comment: I understood what you said. Do document readings take place according to the type of query? Because I will always get records within a month, I believe I have 6,000 records per month in this collection, in this case 6,000 readings. If I make two queries with the same query will I do two readings in Cloud Firestore?

Comment: A query will cost a document read for each document transferred to the client.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the answers I could understand what I needed!